# PHP Sort pictures by biggest width and where width is bigger than height

Tags: php, height, width, usort

I have an array like this one:

```
 array(
    0 => array(
       width => "213",
       height => "50"
    ),
    1 => array(
       width => "120",
       height => "204"
    )
 ) etc...
```

Now I want to order this array by the pictures with the biggest width worth and where the width is bigger than the height.

My try to do this was that, using `usort()`:

```
usort($results['bossresponse']['images']['results'], function($a, $b) { 
            return $b['width'] - $a['width'];
});
```

But it sort's the pictures just for their width, not if the picture have a bigger width than the height. Is it possible with usort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
usort($results['bossresponse']['images']['results'], function($a, $b) { 
    //Case if A has bigger width than height but B doesn't
    if($a["width"]>$a["height"] && !($b["width"]>$b["height"])) return -1;

    //Case if B has bigger width than height but A doesn't
    if(!($a["width"]>$a["height"]) && $b["width"]>$b["height"]) return 1;

    //They both/neither have bigger width than height, so compare widths
    if($a["width"]>$b["width"]) return -1;
        elseif($b["width"]>$a["width"]) return 1;
        else return 0;
});
```